# Cómo cambiar carpeta de destino de descarga de screenshot generado y guardado en javascript

Tags: javascript, html

En este código se genera y se descarga una captura de pantalla. Por defecto se descarga a la carpeta "Downloads". Cómo puedo cambiar esta carpeta de destino a la cual se descarga la captura?. Necesito que lo haga a C:\Screen\

```js
html2canvas(document.body, {
  onrendered(canvas) {
    var link = document.getElementById('dwnld');;
    var image = canvas.toDataURL();
    link.href = image;
    link.download = 'ScreenShot.png';
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

  <title>Screenshot and download</title>
</head>

<body>

  <a id="dwnld">Tomar screenshot y descargar</a>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hola lo que estas tratando de hacer no es posible, ya que cada navegador te trae una opción para que el usuario elija la carpeta de destino en donde se descargaran todas las cosas de internet, porque es necesario cambiar la carpeta? o cual es el fin de realizar eso.

Answer (score 0):

No es posible programar algo para establecer la carpeta de destino de las descargas en los navegadores web. Esto es una configuración de los navegadores web que cada usuario puede personalizar y corresponde con una decisión de diseño para proteger a los usuarios.

Cada navegador tiene su forma de configurar esto. En Google Chrome, por ejemplo, esta configuración se encuentra en Configuración > Configuración avanzada > Descargas:

[image: Configuración de descargas en Google Chrome]